# getAllTabInfo Iterate through response

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, custom-console-components

I want to iterate through the response of getAllTabInfo js function. I have the following function:

```
navigateTo: function(component, recId) {
        var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        navEvt.setParams({
            "recordId": recId
        });
        navEvt.fire();
        window.setTimeout(
            $A.getCallback(function() {
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            }), 2000
        );

        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getAllTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
       })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
```

Under console.log(response);, i want to iterate through the results, get the tabids of the open tabs that have a specific title, and close those tabs.
How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your console log should give you all the information you need to loop through and close the tabs based on a title.

You can try something like this, and it will work, but please build off of this example, and don't just delete tabs based on a hardcoded tab title

```
var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
workspaceAPI.getAllTabInfo().then(function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))); // this will give you a better debug log.
    var tabTitleToDelete = 'Title to Delete' // Change this to the title string you want to delete...NOTE: this seems bad, it might be better to work on a dynamic way to do this, but this was your ask...
    for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        var tabTitle = response[i].title; // title of the tab - usually the record "Name" field, if this is a "customTitle..."
        var customTitle = response[i].customTitle; // use this title if you have given a title to the tabs that you are wanting to close
        var tabId = response[i].tabId; // this is the id you'll need to call the closeTab function

        // You can add more customizations to this, like checking if this is a parent tab, or a subtab, or if it's focused, then not to close it
        // just use response[i].attributeName in your 'response' to figure this out.
        if(tabTitle === tabTitleToDelete) {
            workspaceAPI.closeTab({tabId: tabId});
        }

    }

})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```